# Diagonalization of a 2x2 self-adjoined (hermitian) matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigenvector, eigenvalue

Diagonalizing a 2x2 hermitian matrix is simple, it can be done analytically. However, when it comes to calculating the eigenvalues and eigenvectors over >10^6 times, it is important to do it as efficient as possible. Especially if the off-diagonal elements can vanish it is not possible to use one formula for the eigenvectors: An if-statement is necessary, which of course slows down the code. Thus, I thought using Eigen, where it's stated that the diagonalization of 2x2 and 3x3 matrices is optimized, would be still a good choice:

using

```
const std::complex<double> I ( 0.,1. );
inline double block_distr ( double W )
{
  return (-W/2. + rand() * W/RAND_MAX);
}
```

a test-loop would be

```
...
SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Matrix<complex< double >, 2, 2> > ces;
Matrix<complex< double >, 2, 2> X;

for (int i = 0 ; i <iter_MAX; ++i) {
  a00=block_distr(100.);
  a11=block_distr(100.);
  re_a01=block_distr(100.);
  im_a01=block_distr(100.);

  X(0,0)=a00;
  X(1,0)=re_a01-I*im_a01;
  //only the lower triangular part is referenced! X(0,1)=0.; <--- not necessary
  X(1,1)=a11;
  ces.compute(X,ComputeEigenvectors);
}
```

Writing the loop without Eigen, using directly the formulas for eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a hermitian matrix and an if-statement to check if the off diagonal is zero, is a factor of 5 faster. Am I not using Eigen properly or is such an overhead normal? Are there other lib.s which are optimized for small self-adjoint matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the iterative method is used. To use the analytical version for the 2x2 and 3x3, you have to call the [computeDirect](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html#a85cda7e77edf4923f3fc0512c83f6323) function:

```
ces.computeDirect(X);
```

but it is unlikely to be faster than your implementation of the analytic formulas.

Comment: I did some checks using computeDirect and it did not change the calculation time significantly (from 2.7s to 2.6s), unfortunately.
Update: The manual says "Currently only 3x3 matrices for which the sizes are known at compile time are supported"

Comment: The documentation is wrong on that point. The closed form path does exist for 2x2, but for real matrices only, not for complex ones which is why you don't see any difference.